# how to store ATR value on specific time in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

im trying to store the atr value at a specific time. the point is to create atr horizontal levels based on the first 30 minutes of market opening. i tried several values and it looks it works at first but on scrooling back it reads out wrong values. thanks for taking the time to look over the code

```
session = input.session(defval='0930-1600', title='Trading Session')
plot_session = input.session(defval='1000-1600', title='Plotting: add one minute to the 
Pick your own session start')
resol = input.timeframe('30', title='length/time Of Opening Range = Trading Session to 
Plotsesion')
show_today = input(false, title='Show only today')
atr_timefr = input('1', title='ATR Timeframe')
atrLkb = input(14, title='ATR Stop Period')
//atrRes = input.timeframe("D", title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input.float(0.25, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier') 


highTimeFrame = time('D')


//calc for ranges
plt = plot_session
sesstoday = session
sessSpec = session 

//range calculation
hiloreg = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.regular)
sessions(sesstodayw) => time('D', sesstodayw)
bartimeSess = sessions(sesstoday)
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]

high_range = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess, high, 0)
low_range = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess, low, 0)

highRes = request.security(hiloreg, resol, high_range)
lowRes = request.security(hiloreg, resol, low_range)
range_1 = highRes - lowRes


//show today 
istoday = year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and 
dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time) 
is_today = show_today ? istoday and time('1', sessSpec) : time('1', sessSpec)

    
//atr calculation


atrcollect = openRangeMid 
atr = request.security(syminfo.ticker, atr_timefr, ta.atr(atrLkb))
float entry_atr = na
entry_atr := atrcollect[0] > atrcollect[1] ? atr : entry_atr[1]

//PT Highlightning
plot_pt = time('1', plt) ? color.purple : na


//PT1
highRes2 = highRes + range_1 * (3*.1)
lowRes2 = lowRes - (entry_atr * atrMult)
plot(is_today ? highRes2 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)
plot(is_today ? lowRes2 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)

//PT2
highRes3 = highRes2 + range_1 * (3*.1)
lowRes3 = lowRes2 - (entry_atr * atrMult)
plot(is_today ? highRes3 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)
plot(is_today ? lowRes3 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)

//PT3
highRes4 = highRes3 + (entry_atr * atrMult)
lowRes4 = lowRes3 - (entry_atr * atrMult)
plot(is_today  ? highRes4 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)
plot(is_today  ? lowRes4 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it reads out the wrong values, possibly with a screenshot? Like what values you expect and what values you get.

Comment: hi baris, thank you for the response. im trying to get the highest atr value from the daily time given like the high from candle in above code. for example what is highest atr from daily 09:30 to 10;00. at the moment i tried to solve this with the current atr read from event at openmidrange  when i create the midrange opening breakout line. i dont know how to get the atr value from that specific time and create the pt 1 with atr * atr multi im trying to update the ORB indicator with ATR profit targets screenshot at https://paste.pics/EXYK9 many thanks for the response

Comment: ok maybe i solved it with following solution : atr = request.security(syminfo.ticker, atr_timefr, ta.atr(atrLkb))
atr_range= ta.valuewhen(newbarSess, atr, 0)
highest_atr= request.security(hiloreg, resol, atr_range)                                                 but when i try  following //PT1
highRes2 = highRes + (highest_atr* atrMult)
lowRes2 = lowRes - (highest_atr* atrMult)
plot(is_today  and close > highRes ? highRes2 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=3)
plot(is_today ? lowRes2 : na, color=plot_pt, linewidth=2)                                                     the PT high line ends

Comment: the line ends up all over the chart. cant get my head around this https://paste.pics/EY0T2

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example of how you can get data from a specific time period.

The idea is, create a time window where you want to retrieve data from. Then, use that window to do all your calculations. [Source](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time)

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
time_window = input.session(defval="1000-1100", title="Time Window")

var max_atr = 0.0
my_atr = ta.atr(14)
is_in_window = time(timeframe.period, time_window + ":1234567")

if is_in_window
    // We are entering allowed hours; reset atr
    if not is_in_window[1]
        max_atr := my_atr
    else
        // We are in allowed hours; track atr
        max_atr := math.max(max_atr, my_atr)
        
plot(not is_in_window? max_atr : na, "Max ATR", color.blue, 3, plot.style_circles)
```

Here you can see that there is a time window where we are kinda blind and do our calculations. When we are out of the time window, we don't do any more calculations and use the last value. Therefore, we have a fixed value.

[image]